# ELSA package (spatial association): My categorical raster data do not behave as intended

Tags: gis, raster, spatial, r-raster, terra

I've started working with the `elsa` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elsa/vignettes/elsa.html) to measure entropy-based spatial association for categorical data, but it revolves a lot around raster data, of which I have little previous experience. 
My data comes from a .tif file whose pixel values I have reclassified to 5 categories in QGIS.

```
library(raster)

r <- new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "C:\\Users\\bluew\\Desktop\\stefano\\ELSA\\are_1.81_3003.tif", 
                              datanotation = "FLT4S", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
                              NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
                              toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = c(rows = 1L), blockcols = c(cols = 1062L), 
                              driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", 
                                                                         values = logical(0), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, 
                                                                         fromdisk = TRUE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), haveminmax = TRUE, 
                                                                         min = 1, max = 5, band = 1L, unit = "", names = "are_1.81_3003"), 
    legend = new(".RasterLegend", type = character(0), values = logical(0), 
                 color = logical(0), names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), 
    title = character(0), extent = new("Extent", xmin = 1478031.1565, 
                                       xmax = 1563459.1172, ymin = 4933676.6029, ymax = 5009134.9516), 
    rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), 
                                    transfun = function () 
                                      NULL), ncols = 1062L, nrows = 662L, crs = new("CRS", 
                                                                                    projargs = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"), 
    srs = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs", 
    history = list(), z = list())

r <- setMinMax(r,force=T)
```

I submit this to the `elsa` function:

```
library(elsa)

e <- elsa(r,d=500,categorical = T) #the d argument defines the neighbourhood of each pixel
```

This should result in a `RasterLayer` object which contains the ELSA values for each pixel, but my result is somewhat strange:

```
library(tmap)

cl <- colorRampPalette(c('darkblue','yellow','red','black'))(100)

tm_shape(e) + tm_raster(palette= cl, title = "ELSA",style="cont") +
tm_layout(legend.outside = T)
```

As you can see below, it looks as though the values are only being calculated at the edges of each category, which doesn't make sense.

[image: Example]

The examples provided in the vignette I've linked above look nothing like this, but there's no further documentation on how to prepare the raster data, and as I've said I have very little experience on how to handle them. 
It might very well have something to do with the way I have reclassified the raster in QGIS, but I really can't tell; I've tried to compare my raster with the ones provided in the package, but I can't spot significant differences. 
Could anybody point me in the direction of what might be causing this result?
Thank you to anyone who gives advice.

Comment: please provide a reporducible example. The raster you create cannot be used because it depends on a file that we do not have nor wish to have: "C:\\Users\\bluew\\Desktop\\stefano\\ELSA\\are_1.81_3003.tif"

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I hadn't noticed. I found a solution which I describe in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the "border" effect was simply a consequence of the raster resolution being too high, which was not ideal for the type of data which I am working on, because the different categories tend to cover large areas; I changed the resolution of the raster files in QGIS to a more reasonable amount (appr. 2500 meters) and the result is much more in line with what I was expecting.
[image]